# How to get component instance in vue3's directive hooks?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue 2, I can get the component instance by `vnode.componentInstance`. However, there is no `componentInstance` in Vue 3's `vnode`. Vue 3's `vnode` has a `component` property. Unfortunately, I found it was `null` in my custom directive `beforeMount` hook. So, how do I get the component instance in Vue 3's directive hooks?

Answer (score 2):

The component instance is now under [`binding.instance`](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#directive-hooks):

```js
const MyDirective = {
  beforeMount(el, binding, vnode) {     
    console.log('component', binding.instance)
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-directive-component-instance?file=src/main.js)

Normally, `binding.instance` would be the component *instance* (hence the name), but there seems to be a [Vue bug](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2562) that causes `binding.instance` to be the component definition instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that binding.instance is a Proxy in the console output. If I have a method called testFunc in the HelloWorld component, how can I call this method via the Proxy?

Comment: The Proxy is of the component instance, so treat it as if it were the component itself. If the method is exposed, you can call it directly from the Proxy instance (e.g. `binding.instance.testFunc()`).

Comment: I try to add a method called testFunc in your demo's HelloWorld component, and call the method like this: `binding.instance.testFunc()`. But it said testFunc is not a function. Can you give me some help or tips?

Comment: @guogangi That should've worked, but it turns out to be a [Vue bug](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2562) that prevents it from working.

Comment: Although it didn't end up solving the problem, your information was very helpful, thanks